# How to create a summary table without creating a new table in Power BI

Tags: group-by, powerbi, powerquery, summarize

I am trying to summarize a table in Power BI Desktop without creating a new table. To be more specific, here is the original table.
[image]

I would like to summarize this table on "id" column, and create a column which includes the maximum of "fe2" column. If I use SUMMARIZE dax function, it creates a new table. However, my data is large and I do not want to make a new table. I would like to summarize the original table similar to what we can do in Power Query Editor using Groupby option.

I appreciate it if you help me with that.
Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a classic XY-problem. What do you want to achieve, e.g. what do you want to show in the Power BI canvas?

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, if you want to obtain a summary within a column, you can do so by using functions that return a scalar value. Here's an example using DAX expressions:

```
column = 
    VAR check = 'Tablename'[id]
    VAR summarization = SUMMARIZE('Tablename', 'Tablename'[id], "fe2Max", MAX('Tablename'[fe2]))
    RETURN
        COUNTROWS(FILTER(summarization, 'Tablename'[id] = check))
```

This DAX expression calculates the maximum value of the 'fe2' column for each 'id' in the 'Tablename' table and returns the count of rows where the 'id' matches the 'check' variable.

However, please note that in Power BI, you can't directly place a summary of multiple values inside a single column, as multiple values cannot be converted to a scalar value within a column. If you need to create a new table or perform more complex summarization tasks, you can also utilize functions like SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, GROUPBY with CURRENTGROUP(), and SUMMARIZE to summarize your data accordingly."